# heroku failing to deploy my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rubygems

I am not able to push my rails app on heroku. Below is error message i get when i try to push rails app on heroku.

> Ruby app detected Compiling Ruby/Rails sh: 1: Gemfile: not found  !  !
>   There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue  !       !
>   [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected
>   ':', expecting end-of-input - group: production do  !     ^. Bundler
>   cannot continue.  !       !     #  from
>   /tmp/build_c114d933dd903e377866500bea22e827/Gemfile:50  !     # 
>   -------------------------------------------  !     #  !     >  group: production do  !     #  gem 'pg'  !     # 
>   -------------------------------------------  !  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

This is what my gemfile looks like.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group: production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Is your app working on local machine ? can you run `bundle install` and then `bundle update` I guess you  have made some changes in your gem file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here was an error parsing Gemfile: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input - group: production**

As above log...It is Just syntax error

```
group: production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

update it from

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. You are getting this error because of two mistakes you made in your gem file

(1) you forgot to define version of your `gem 'byebug'` in your gem file.

(2) you wrote`group: production do` which suppose to be `group :production do`I am pretty sure you will not be able to run your app locally either until you fix these both issues.

Add `gem 'byebug',  '3.4.0'` in your gem file. you only have `gem 'byebug'` if you just add `'3.4.0'` secondly write `group :production do` instead of `group: production do` at 4th line from bottom of your gem file

once you add make these changes to your gem file make sure you run `bundle install`  then `bundle update`

after successfully you do above process you can run below command to upload your app to heroku.

```
git init

git add .

git commit -am "some comment"

git push heroku master

heroku open
```

Comment: can you make this post more helpful to others by clicking on tick mark button (on left side of this answer) and up voting it once if it was helpful answer to you. @stanleywendo

Comment: Make sure you mark right answer to the answer which has solved your problem. in that way that answer can be helpful to other users too. @stanleywendo